# How do I skip the first index in an enhanced-for loop, when the loop is of type "javafx.scene.control.Tab"?

Tags: java, javafx, foreach

I'm trying to set TabIds and each tab is getting its Id and Text from a list called entityList. The problem is that number of tabs is dependent on the size of this entityList + an additional first tab(where user enters entityList), and I got working everything well, except that the first Tab should always be named "Overview".

I know how to set that, but I don't know how to skip the first tab in the enhanced-for loop (so that it starts setting ID starting from the second tab, which would contain entityList's first string). Following is my method:

```
@FXML
public void currentTabIndex() {
    ObservableList<Tab> tabID = mainTabPane.getTabs();
    int i=0;
    //tabID.get(0).setId("Overview"); --> can't figure out where this should be placed
    //tabID.get(0).setText("Overview"); --> and this too

    for (Tab loop:tabID) {
        for(;i<tabID.size()-1;) {
            loop.setId(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
            loop.setText(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `if(i == 0)` mabye?

Comment: Why did you use second `for` if you break from the first process ?

Comment: `for (Tab loop : tabID.subList(1, tabID.size()))`

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine the first loop is to go through each Tab in the tabpane and the second is to go through the `entityList` which is an arrayList of Entity Data Model, and contains different entity values at each iteration.

Comment: I see a redundant ,as far as I know each Tab(loop) has only one `ID`and one `Text` ,and I see that he used a second `for` loop but he used  `break` after the first iteration.

Comment: Edit** -- the first loop is to go through each Tab in the tabpane and the second is to go through the `entityList` which is an arrayList of Entity Data Model, and contains different entity values at each iteration.  If I don't break the inner loop after first iteration, the current Tab in the loop will always have the last entityName from my entityList (also the reason why I moved my 'int i` initialization and iteration outside the for loop declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an enhanced for loop it's impossible to skip the first iteration. It's possible to work around this by introducing a check but I recommend alternative approaches:

You could use a conventional for loop using a iterator

```
for (Iterator<Tab> iterator = tabID.listIterator(1); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Tab loop = iterator.next();

    ...
}
```

or iterating over a sublist:

```
for (Tab loop : tabID.subList(1, tabID.size())) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I preferred the second option, and it works great! I did not know that enhanced loop had this limitation, thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) provide a methods for your case ,You can get the `stream()` from your `OvbservableList` after that  use [skip method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) like this :

```
  tabID.stream().skip(1).forEach(loop->{
             loop.setId(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
             loop.setText(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
             i++;

        });
```

`skip` Parameters : the number of leading elements to skip start from **1**.

**Edit :** based on @Radiodef comment

For some reasons ,if you see that an enhanced `for` loop is necessary for you,you can convert the code to :

```
   for (Tab loop : (Iterable<Tab>) tabID.stream().skip(1)::iterator) {
        ......
}
```

Comment: Maybe just a curiosity, but this can also be converted in to an enhanced `for` loop with `for (Tab loop : (Iterable<Tab>) tabID.stream().skip(1)::iterator) {...}`.

Comment: Thank you for different approaches, I appreciate all the help :) Also, enhanced for loop is necessary here for other functionalities I need to add, so the skip(index) was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this would be to add a variable to keep track if the first index was processed yet, and if it wasnt then skip that iteration of the loop.

To do this, change this code:

```
     for (Tab loop:tabID) {
    for(;i<tabID.size()-1;) {
        loop.setId(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
        loop.setText(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
        i++;
        break;
    }
    }
```

To this code:

```
     boolean skippedFirst = false;
    for (Tab loop:tabID) {
    if(!skippedFirst){
        skippedFirst = true;
        }else {
    for(;i<tabID.size()-1;) {
        loop.setId(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
        loop.setText(entityList.get(i).getEntitytName());
        i++;
        break;
    }
    }
    }
```